# Where does MediaWiki stores variable with Common.[js|css] in execute function?

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

I'm on writing my own skin for MediaWiki (1.23), and can't find which variable stores content of Common.js|css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those go in the 'site' RL module which is part of the 'bottomscripts' data. BaseTemplate deals with that via your `$this->printTrail()` call.